# Pull weights while running

Tags: running, strength

Previously I had asked about carrying hand weights while running.

Can we pull weights while running? Tie a rope to our hip and the weight.
I am planning to run on the beach sand nearby.

My question is, is there any use in doing this? Will I improve my speed or my strength or both?

Comment: I can share a video of what I am trying to say, if you people want me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three common ways of increasing resistance while running:

1. Hill running - the downside is your form has to change.
2. Resistance parachutes - you can maintain your normal form, and the added resistance is useful for increasing your strength and power while running (although not a replacement for strength training in the gym)
3. Pushing or pulling a weighted prowler sled - this isn't really running anymore, but is a really good conditioning and endurance/strength exercise for the legs, hips, and core.

   - I think your idea of pulling weights falls into this category.

Comment: That helps, thank you. So nothing against doing this, correct?

Comment: I think I'd find weights in sand awkward because of non-uniform resistance (sometimes the weights will dig in, sometimes they'll skip across the surface, etc.). But other than that, I can't think of anything negative.